# Sourcing oddball stacked USB-A connector

Tags: pcb, usb, components, component-selection

I'm looking for an oddball stacked USB connector to repair a piece of equipment. I can't use the standard form factor, because it won't fit into the enclosure properly.

I've gone through mouser and newark and several other websites and can't seem to find anything that matches.  A verbal description: Imagine a standard 2-port stacked PCB mount USB-A connector. Now imagine that the 8 pins are inset vertically about 5mm, such that the connector is mounted into a cutout in the pcb, and dangles below the pcb a smidge.

A sloppy side-view picture:

[image: Side view of component]

Comment: Arghh... I knew it was a matter of terminology.

Comment: Trying, can't find a dual-port one anywhere, and it's a horizontal mount. Struggling.

Comment: ok, the picture is unclear as to the orientation ... at first i thought that it is upright type .... that is a mid-mount package for sure ... perhaps you could make an adapter board using an pc mount vertical connector ... the kind that points upward when it is soldered on a pcb

Comment: Thanks. I still haven't had any luck finding the part, but at least I know what it's called and what to ask for.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the part eventually. The search term was “female dual port sinking plate”.